# Submitting Rows of Input Fields to Server

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have an HTML table of Input elements.  How do I submit just the rows with edited fields to the server?

---

### | 1 | A | B | C | D | E |

### | 2 | A | B | C | D | E |

### | 3 | A | B | C | D | E |

If 2B is changed, I want to send row 2.

Answer (score 0):

create dynamically the inputs, add a event listener to each one (onchange) to add the input to  an array, on other event get the data of the inputs in the array, send it and clean the array